# DataTables wont load with AJAX and MYSQL

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax, datatables

Somehow, I'm getting an invalid JSON response out of this code. The goal is to display the SQL Data in the table with all features as search and sort with https://datatables.net/. Where could be the problem?

**GET.PHP**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
$query ="SELECT * FROM users"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $results = ["sEcho" => 1,
          "iTotalRecords" => count($row),
          "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($row),
          "aaData" => $row ];
        echo json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
} else {
    echo "empty table";
}

$mysqli->close();
```

**GET.PHP RESPONSE**

```
{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 2,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 2,
    "aaData": {
        "id": "26",
        "name": "test",
        "pass": "2"
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#my-example').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "get.php",
    "aoColumns": [{ 
        mData: 'name'
      }, {
        mData: 'pass'
    }]
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table id="my-example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>pass</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Share the result you got from json_encode($results)

Comment: When I look into the network tab what the ajax call gets, there is nothing. So the error must be already in the php.

Comment: Following DataTables [documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax), the array returned by your PHP code is false.

Comment: By false I mean wrong haha, not the boolean false.

Comment: But what causes this, it should put all rows in  $data[] = $row; with this?

Answer (score 0):

The array your PHP code is returning should look like this, it is an obligation for it to have `data` as the data you're returning, and `error` as the eventual errors :

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Text going into the first column",
      "second column",
      "third column"
    ]
  ]
}
```

So in your case your array would look this this :

```
[
  "data": [
    [
      "1",
      count($data),
      count($data),
      $data
    ]
  ]
]
```

Also in the loop you need to get [each row separately](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) by using `$row['column']`.

[Test case](http://jsfiddle.net/wx1odf4k/1/)

Comment: Sorry, i'm pretty new to this stuff and I don't unterstand where to start. So the array in the php under $results needs to be structured as seen above? And the while must be for each column? I'm a bit confused. Sorry.

Comment: If you can't understand my answer I think you should start by going through a basic MYSQL/PHP tutorial. And read the datatables page I gave you the link to in a comment of your question.

Comment: Okay. Sorry. I'll try my best.

Comment: I updated the code so now I get a vaild JSON response from the php, but the js still not works.

Comment: It still states that there is a "invalid json". Even though as can be seen above it show a working json output.